# Date time parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which requires user to type the start date and also allow them to choose from calendar. I was wondering if its possible to enter the date as a string. Right now, I have a text field with calendar and I would like the user to enter date[06302015] instead of [06/30/2015]

can we omit the dashes and still have the report format it to date?

Comment: If you want the end user typing in text values.. your query will have to take that parameter value and change it to a date format for the parameter to work correctly.. You will be comparing / filtering on a date column for sure.. and error trapping will necessary as users can type what ever... best is to stick with calendar... you can just type in the date with the slashes and it will work and you don't have to use the date picker.

Comment: Bear in mind that as a string, '06302015' > '05302018' (not the intent).  But as a date, '2018-05-30' > '2015-05-03'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your parameter type to "Text".
2. Add a second "Hidden" parameter (as Date/Time data Type) that takes the LAST_DATE_EDITED as an input into the 2nd parameter's default value using the expression: `=DateValue(Mid(Parameters!LAST_DATE_EDITED.Value,1,2) & "/" & Mid(Parameters!LAST_DATE_EDITED.Value,3,2) & "/" & Mid(Parameters!LAST_DATE_EDITED.Value,5,4))`
   ***(Not tested, but it should be close)***
3. Then use the 2nd parameter in your report instead of LAST_DATE_EDITED.

If the user inputs an incorrectly formatted string of numbers, uses text, etc., SSRS will throw an exception.

IMO, this isn't the most elegant solution and it demands user input that is prone to errors.  Not what I would implement (I would have the users use the built in DateTime picker and train them to use valid separators such as periods, slashes or dashes or just use the calendar control).

Answer (score 2):

The type of a parameter can be changed from Parameter Properties like below.
This will remove the Calendar and it will be only a Text box.

[image]

Comment: so how is this going to help OP filter on a date time column? Sure.. this allows the end user to type in text.. but the table filtering won't work as is!

Comment: I would like to have calendar displayed as well, Is it possible to have the date picker available as well

Comment: You should mention that if the user wants the date as text, then the text date would need to be converted to a date in the code. Might be best to leave the current date parameter and ALLOW NULLS then add another parameter for the text date and only check if Date param is NULL (`DECLARE @DATE_internal as DATE = ISNULL(@DATE, CAST(RIGHT(@TEXT_DATE, 4) + '-' + LEFT(@TEXT_DATE, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@TEXT_DATE, 3, 2) AS DATE) )`